# Ionic Framework how to add form for mobile number with country code?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I want to add a form for entering Mobile Number. But want to ask the user to enter the country code as well so that a verification SMS can be sent over the number.

What I want is:

Enter Your Mobile Number. : |(country code)| |(mobile no.)|

How can I do this?

Comment: Take two input elements for both country code and mobile number... while sending SMS combine both numbers and send

Comment: can you show sample code of it?

Comment: It's unclear what you are really asking for? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sample code:

```
<input class="input" ng-model="countryCode" placeholder="Country Code"></input>
<input class="input" ng-model="mobileNumber" placeholder="Mobile Number"></input>
```

Comment: Yes this is what I wanted... But how to make country code input element smaller than mobile number?

Comment: how to make country code form smaller than mobile number form so that only 3-4 characters can be entered..??

Comment: please go through this link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome

Comment: use maxlength="5" in html

Comment: @HARITHAUPPARA, for the same question, i want to add dropdown with all the country codes instead of entering country code manually. How can i do that