# maxlength not working with input type="number" ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I try to define maxlength of a number input.

```
 <label class="item item-input">
 <i class="icon ion-android-call placeholder-icon"></i>
 <input type="number"  placeholder="Phone number " maxlength="8">
 </label>
```

How can i reesolve it please.

Comment: Thats true. You can use type `tel` then it works. By the way, if you use your app for ios then you didn't have `number` type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
   <input type="tel " maxlength="6">
```

Comment: This is not an acceptable answer if using a web browser on the desktop as there is nothing to stop you adding letters into the field. There seems currently to be no solution for this scenario in Ionic so far :-(

Comment: Okay this link makes things clearer along with a workaround using maxlength and the pattern attribute of the input tag: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome/18510925#18510925

Answer (score 4):

```
 <input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="6">
```

This will validate the numbers pattern too :)