# How to focus next input field on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a mobile application. I want to implement this function where on pressing the key, the next input field is focused. I tried many things but none seem to be working. This is my code. I tried using onClick but when i touch it, it goes to the next field.

```
<input type="number" class="mobile-verify pass" maxlength="1" name="code[]" />
<input type="number" class="mobile-verify pass" maxlength="1" name="code[]" />
<input type="number" class="mobile-verify pass" maxlength="1" name="code[]" />
<input type="number" class="mobile-verify pass" maxlength="1" name="code[]" />
```

I want a pure **Jquery** or **Javascript** solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about:

```
$('input.mobile-verify.pass').on('keyup', function() {
    if ($(this).val()) {
        $(this).next().focus();
    }
});
```

So on key up, if there is a value, focus the next. Using keyup allows you to validate the contents rather than skipping right away. They might switch to number mode on iOS for example which would trigger the focus if you simply use keypress.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qaGKzk

Answer (score 6):

Use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```js
$(".mobile-verify.pass").on("keypress", function(e){
  $(this).next().trigger("focus");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" class="mobile-verify pass" name="code[]" />
<input type="number" class="mobile-verify pass" name="code[]" />
<input type="number" class="mobile-verify pass" name="code[]" />
<input type="number" class="mobile-verify pass" name="code[]" />
```

Side note: Find another solution for the `maxlength` attribute functionality, as per [maxlength ignored for input type=“number”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18510925/6439240)

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript and events `keypress` and `focus` and also key numbers validation:

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('.mobile-verify.pass')
  .forEach(el => el.onkeyup = e => e.target.value && el.nextElementSibling.focus())
```

```css
input {
  display: flex;
  margin: 4px 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="mobile-verify pass" maxlength="1" name="code[]" />
<input type="number" class="mobile-verify pass" maxlength="1" name="code[]" />
<input type="number" class="mobile-verify pass" maxlength="1" name="code[]" />
<input type="number" class="mobile-verify pass" maxlength="1" name="code[]" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [.keypress()](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) and [.focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) functions in jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Use .[keypress()](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) and [.focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/)

The snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("input.mobile-verify.pass").keypress(function(){
    $(this).next().trigger('focus');
    //or $(this).next().focus(); 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="number" class="mobile-verify pass" maxlength="1" name="code[]" />
<input type="number" class="mobile-verify pass" maxlength="1" name="code[]" />
<input type="number" class="mobile-verify pass" maxlength="1" name="code[]" />
<input type="number" class="mobile-verify pass" maxlength="1" name="code[]" />
```

With **full JS**

```js
var allElements = document.querySelectorAll('.mobile-verify.pass');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
  var el = allElements[i];
  el.addEventListener("keypress", function () {
    this.nextSibling.nextSibling.focus();
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="number" class="mobile-verify pass" maxlength="1" name="code[]" />
<input type="number" class="mobile-verify pass" maxlength="1" name="code[]" />
<input type="number" class="mobile-verify pass" maxlength="1" name="code[]" />
<input type="number" class="mobile-verify pass" maxlength="1" name="code[]" />
```

**NB :** if you ask, why 2 nextSibling, the answer is that the first sibling is the text representing the small space between 2 elements

Comment: I really like this solution. However it requires that the next input field follows the previous. Sadly I can't use this because I have a dynamic number of `<span>` tags between <input> tags :(

Answer (score -1):

Others have already written the solutions. I just wanted to add that the part

```
[].slice.call
```

is what solved my problem. I couldn't focus an element because it was of type Element, and not HtmlElement. But somehow that part of code is converting my querySelectorAll list of Elements to HtmlElements.

Thank you Yosvel Quintero