# programmatically navigate focus in material-ui

Tags: focus, material-ui, autosuggest

I have an autosuggest component (with a TextField from material-ui), my issue is that after selecting a value from the autosuggest (eg. with the mouse), the suggestion remains open since the input still has the focus

How do I navigate to the next focusable element programmatically?

Comment: Do you mean AutoComplete? Can you provide online example like AutoComplete Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/jer2r

Comment: no the component is an autosuggest (a react lib), but that's not relevant for the question.
I think the answer is rather in the html like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40304963/how-to-focus-next-input-field-on-keypress/40305042

Comment: can you provide mini example?

Comment: The mini example is just a <TextField/> tag where I want to loose focus on a given event

This answer contains an answer in pure js, i'll try that
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208161/focus-next-element-in-tab-index

currentElement.nextElementSibling.focus();