# HTML mobile web input with enterkeyhint not focussing on next input if type is text

Tags: html, forms, web, mobile, android-softkeyboard

I'm working on an HTML form for a web app. I'm adding the `enterkeyhint` attribute to indicate and navigate to the next input until the last one submits the form.
The problem is that `enterkeyhint` doesn't navigate to the next input if its type is `type=text`.
This happens on `Chrome/83.0.4103.101` for Android 7. In Safari the hints button appears but they all do nothing.

Example:

```
    <form (submit)="submitForm()">
        <div>
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" enterkeyhint="next" inputmode="text" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Email</label>
            <input type="email" inputmode="email" enterkeyhint="next" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Comments</label>
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

- Focusing on `Name` input, the `Next` button doesn't do anything.
- Focusing on `Email` input, it navigates to any next input (`Comments`)

Now, if I change the `type=email` for `type=text` it doesn't navigate to the next input.

Similar behavior happens for `type=tel`. It does navigate to the next input of the form.

Am I missing something to make this work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`enterkeyhint` is just a hint to the browser what to display on the virtual keyboard, but you need to implement the actual behaviour yourself. See for example [Focus Next Element In Tab Index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208161/focus-next-element-in-tab-index), or [How to focus next input field on keypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40304963/how-to-focus-next-input-field-on-keypress) if your DOM is simple enough that the input fields are siblings with the default tab order.

From the [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#attr-enterkeyhint):

> The `enterkeyhint` content attribute is an enumerated attribute that specifies what action label (or icon) to present for the enter key on virtual keyboards. This allows authors to customize the presentation of the enter key in order to make it more helpful for users.

There is nothing in the spec to suggest that `enterkeyhint` actually affects the *behaviour* of the Enter key.