# Number input. HTML

Tags: html, css, regex

How can I create the number input in which user will be able to type only numbers which consist of five digits? I tried this but user still can type as many digits as he/she wants.

```
 <input type="number" placeholder="1" min="1" max="99999">
```

There is no opportunity to use JavaScript in my project.

Comment: You can validate the content with Javascript.

Comment: There is no opportunity to use JavaScript in my project.

Comment: Then validate it on the back-end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I limit possible inputs in a HTML5 "number" element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-can-i-limit-possible-inputs-in-a-html5-number-element)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maxlength ignored for input type="number" in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome)

Comment: [`<input type="text" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" placeholder="1" minlength="0" maxlength="5" />`](https://jsfiddle.net/0ebyq0r9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below:

```
 <input name="somename"
oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
type = "number"
maxlength = "5"
```

/>

Comment: The OP said: "there is no opportunity to use JavaScript in my project".

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 'pattern' attribute.

According to the docs

> The pattern attribute specifies a regular expression that the 
>   element's value is checked against.

For your case, you can add a pattern attribute to the HTML as follows

```
pattern="[0-9]{5}"
```

`[0-9]` specifies that the character entered should be a number and `{5}` specifies that there should be 5 digits.

Thus your complete HTML would be as follows

```
<input type="number" placeholder="1" pattern="[0-9]{5}">
```

Comment: The OP is talking about how many numbers the user can type while typing, i.e. `maxlength`. What doesn't exists for `<input type="number">`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="1" required="required" pattern="[0-9]{1,5}" />

/* 
   Pattern
   0-9 = Only number.
   1,  = Minimum length,
   5  = Maximum Length
*/
/*required="required" attribute also needed*/
```

Best way if you use `JavaScript` form validation.
Thanks.