# Ionic-3 ion-input maxlength attribute not working

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have tried to add `ion-input` for  `maxlength` , `max` attribute but it's not working as per expectation.

```
<ion-input type="number" placeholder="*" maxlength="1"></ion-input>

<ion-input type="number" placeholder="*" max="1"></ion-input>
```

Anyone knows the solution for the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to this post: [maxlength ignored for input type="number" in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome/18510925#18510925)

Maxlength doesn't work on input type="number"

One alternative is suggested here: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/7072
where dilhan119 suggests using type="tel"

A robust solution is to use a form validator, which will prevent form submission (and can show the user an error): https://www.joshmorony.com/advanced-forms-validation-in-ionic-2/

Answer (score 5):

```
HTML:
    <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]=“text” (ionChange)="textareaMaxLengthValidation()"></ion-textarea>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]=“text” (ionChange)="textareaMaxLengthValidation()"></ion-input>


    TS:
    textareaMaxLengthValidation() {
        if (text.length > 50) {
       text= text.slice(0, 50);
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

I found my way out you can use below my code. great this about it is you can keep input type number so android will show keyboard of your desire

put this code in your form builder

```
phone: ['', [Validators.required, this.isValidNumber.bind(this)]]
```

in your ts file add below method

```
isValidNumber(fieldControl: FormControl) {
    if(this.formBuilderGroup) {
      return fieldControl.value.toString().length < 10 ? null : {
        NotEqual: true
      };
    }
  }
```

in above code change formBuilderGroup to whatever your form builder group name it
 is. change 10 to whatever you prefer length

Comment: Thank you!
This is the perfect way for me to create a "confirm password" validator for my project

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled accross this issue recently and I ended up using a solution similar to the one by @Karthick Chandra Sekar, only difference is I used the standard HTML keypress event instead, since ionChange lets the event go through and causes the character to actually be displayed briefly before it gets rid of. Using keypress allows to prevent the event before it actually takes effect. So, this is how it worked out for me:

Html file:

```
<ion-input type="number" (keypress)="limitInputLength($event)"></ion-input>
```

TS code:

```
  limitInputLength($event, maxLength=2) {
      if($event.target.value.length>=maxLength) {
          $event.preventDefault();
          return;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to fix this like below..

```
<ion-input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="4" errorText="Invalid input"></ion-input>
```