# HTML input type "number" to have same behavior as input type "text" for maxlength

Tags: html, forms, input

I'm using in a form an input of type number, like this:

```html
<input class="form-control" id="Parti_NEstudante" name="Parti_NEstudante" type="number" min="0" max="9999999999" step="1" oninput="(validity.valid)||(value='');">
```

When i insert the value if i introduce more than 10 digits all the input is erased, due to the max i implemented..

My question is, instead of erasing my input, is it possible to just block more digits? just like the behavior of "maxlength" of input type "text".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome   Chrome is just behaving correctly. you can add Jquery to save the result though.

Comment: Hum i see. Not worth the trouble then maybe

Comment: if you make the first attempt and post it, I can help you finish it up. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by this way.

```
<input id="Parti_NEstudante" type="number" min="0" max="9999999999">

<script>
    var input = document.getElementById("Parti_NEstudante");

    input.addEventListener("input", function() {
        if (this.value.length > this.max.length) {
            this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.max.length)
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although that didn't work. See this jsfiddle, i tested what you said. http://jsfiddle.net/t656N/2686/

Comment: If you paste whole code to HTML window, it works.
https://jsfiddle.net/psL9tLg5/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=psL9tLg5

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/t656N/2687/   Still doesn't. I tried on my code, also doesn't work

Comment: Ohh, the problem was my "oninput" definition. Thanks so much. Works exactly like i wanted.