# html numeric input allow 6 digits only

Tags: html

I have a input. I want only numeric values.
And I want there to be six numbers only.
How do i do it?
I have:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="YYMMDD" id="myKadA" maxlength="6" style="width:90px !important" onchange="checkMyKad()" size="8"  class="form-control block-centered ic-input" required>
```

There is a css to remove the scroll bar from the input boxes.

```
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
    -webkit-appearance: textfield; 
}
```

Previously it was `input type="text"`  and `maxlength="6"` limited it to six chars long. How do i now specify a number 6 digit only

Comment: if you got the answer then need to accpt the answer

Answer (score 2):

**JAVASCRIPT WAY**

HTML

```
<input type="number" placeholder="YYMMDD" id="myKadA" onkeydown="limit(this, 6);" onkeyup="limit(this, 6);" onkeyup="this.value = minmax(this.value, 0, 6)" required>
```

JS

```
function limit(element, max_chars)
{
    if(element.value.length > max_chars) {
        element.value = element.value.substr(0, max_chars);
    }
}
function minmax(value, min, max) 
{
    if(parseInt(value) < min || isNaN(parseInt(value))) 
        return 0; 
    else if(parseInt(value) > max) 
        return 100; 
    else return value;
}
```

**HTML WAY**

```
<input type="number" placeholder="YYMMDD" id="myKadA" maxlength="6" min="0"  max="6" required>
```

**JQUERY WAY**

```
<input type="number" placeholder="YYMMDD" id="myKadA" min="0" max="6" required>
var max_chars = 6;
$('#myKadA').keydown( function(e){
    if ($(this).val().length >= max_chars) { 
        $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0, max_chars));
    }
});
$("#myKadA").change(function() {
      var max = parseInt($(this).attr('max'));
      var min = parseInt($(this).attr('min'));
      if ($(this).val() > max)
      {
          $(this).val(max);
      }
      else if ($(this).val() < min)
      {
          $(this).val(min);
      }       
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<input type="number" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length==6) return false;"/>
```

or else you can change the input type to "month"

```
<input type="month" min="2018-03" value="2018-05">
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 1):

Use the attribute max and min for input type number

Answer (score 0):

Since `maxlength` attribute is ignored with `<input type"number"/>` as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-maxlength).

You could try adding some validation with javascript using something like:

HTML

```
 <input onKeyDown="validateNum(event, this)" type="text" maxlength="6" max="6" min="6" placeholder="YYMMDD" id="myKadA" style="width:90px !important" onchange="checkMyKad()" class="form-control block-centered ic-input" required>
```

Javascript

```
function validateNum(event, input) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var currVal = input.value ? input.value : "";
  // Checks if the key pressed is a number and the right length
  if(!isNaN(event.key) && currVal.length < 6){
    input.value = currVal + event.key;
  }
  // Backspace functionality
  else if(event.keyCode == 8 && currVal > 0) {
    input.value = input.value.slice(0, -1);
  }  
}
```

Comment: if max is set as 999999, it allows 1234567 to be entered and throws a error. I want to  block the seventh digit from being entered .

Comment: @Jacel try adding a little script like in my edited response

Answer (score 0):

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome) looks like a promising answer to your case.

Comment: Works well to limit to six digits only. But allows characters to be entered.

Comment: @Jacel I found there variety of ideas that all are suited for some cases. I thought that combining some of the solutions would be great to achieve your exact case. I found that many of the answers checking the input only on submit (alerting the user only on submit). in some cases this is great, in others you would like to block the input from inserting more chars. that is why I post the link and not the code. :)

Answer (score 0):

As you have mention in placeholder -YYMMDD
I would suggest you to use input type="date"

Answer (score 0):

Max length will not work with .
You have to make use of jQuery/Javascript.
Below is a working snippet.

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <label for="myKadA" class="control-label">Number:</label>
    <input type="number" id="myKadA" data-max="6" class="form-control" required>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".btn-primary").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var keyObj = $("#myKadA");
        var maxLength = parseInt(keyObj.attr('data-max'));

        if((keyObj).val().length !== maxLength){
            alert("You must enter exactly " + maxLength + " digits");
        }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to write maxlength=6 without quotes. I tried it in react js like this way: maxLength={6}; and it helped me.

Answer (score -2):

If you want only numbers in input field,

```
<input type="number" max="6"/>
```

so it renders into input type number field which allows only 6 digits

Comment: This limits the maximum value of the field to 6, not the number of digits.