# How to set maxlength to input type number in Angular 6?

Tags: html, typescript, angular6

I want to restrict the input type="number" with 10 digits but it doesn't accept as I have set maxlength to input type="text". 
Is there any another way rather than use regex to set maximum length to type="number"?.
Is there any another option available (same as input type="text" maxlength="10"),
to set length for number easily?

Comment: Why not use `max` attribute for number typed inputs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [maxlength ignored for input type="number" in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome)