# the pattern doesn't work in input Number?

Tags: regex, html

Why the pattern in the input number doesn't work, I have the server error when I write `1.1`, `1,1` because in the mvc controller method i should take the `int` type.

`<input type="number" name="Quantity" min="1" title="Пожалуйста, введите количество" placeholder="кол-во" pattern="\d+" required />`

the required  work right.

How make the pattern to have only integer value?

Comment: if you are trying to store 1.1 into an int on the server it would explain the error. 1.1 is not an integer.

Comment: Yes I now but how make the validation pattern to have only integer!

Comment: `step="1"` would also help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping your input in a `form` will make the validation take effect - it won't limit what people can type, but it will stop the form from being submitted if the input typed in isn't an integer.

```js
const calc = () => alert("It worked!")
```

```html
<form onSubmit="calc()">
  <input
    type="number"
    name="Quantity"
    min="1"
    title="Only ints please"
    placeholder="Type here..."
    pattern="\d+"
    required
  />
  
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

If you want to limit what is being typed in the first place, you'll need more complicated JavaScript for that - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13952727/8230810) for an example of how to do that.

Comment: it doesn't help because it was in a form, but  **Lawrence Cherone** was right `step = "1"` help me

Comment: You need to be careful with `step="1"` because it's not hugely backwards-compatible - though if that's not important in your site then that'll work fine. Just be careful that `step="1"` will also let through things like `e` as that counts as a number.

Answer (score 0):

Try `\d+([.,]\d+)?`.

"Digits, possibly followed by a `.` or `,` and more digits".

Comment: I need just integer type, without any float part

Answer (score 0):

You must use javascript since the input contains "1.1" or "1" and not 1.1 or 1. Or you could convert the string to an int in your controller.

In JS, you can use parseInt(number, base), such as

```js
let i = "42.5243";

let j = parseInt(i);
console.log(j); // 42
```

EDIT with snippet in comment :

```html
<input type="number" name="Quantity" title="Пожалуйста, введите количество" placeholder="кол-во" pattern="\d+" required oninput="validity.valid ? this.save = value : value = this.save;" />
```

it won't allow the user to encode anything else than an integer.

Comment: It is one easy way, but how make by validation, because in my project the peple make order and choose the quantity of the product

Comment: Well, merging your input and a similar one I had answer previously, I came up with   <input type="number" min="0" name="Quantity" min="1" title="Пожалуйста, введите количество" placeholder="кол-во" pattern="\d+" required oninput="validity.valid ? this.save = value : value = this.save;" />. it won't allow the user to input anything else than integer. src : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55119386/input-number-does-not-limit-decimal-when-0-is-typed