# HTML Input type number is not working with maxlength

Tags: html, maxlength, input-type-range

I'm using below html tag and not able to get the restrictions on numbers, I need user to enter 12 digit only however as per HTML tag by default 'maxlength' does not work with `<input type ="number">`, I tried min and max tag, it did not help either.

Could you share if any way to do it in HTML only?

```
<input type="number" name="Aadhar" maxlength="12" placeholder="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}" required>
```

Comment: I notice you're using a number input but the placeholder and pattern are not a number (xxxx-xxxx-xxxx). Is it possible this works any better if you use a text input?

Comment: I tried input text and  it restrict the length however it takes alphanumeric numbers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I limit possible inputs in a HTML5 "number" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-can-i-limit-possible-inputs-in-a-html5-number-element)

Answer (score 4):

Max length will not work with <input type="number". Maybe you can read this [click here to read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34641129/7722149) to resolve ur problem

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `maxlength` attribute is not supported for inputs that are type `number`. Therefore, the best approach is to use JS. Please refer to the following documentation and they might provide some clarity.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefmaxlength
- https://html.com/attributes/input-maxlength/
- [maxlength ignored for input type="number" in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome)

Answer (score 2):

Please use this.

```
<input type="text" name="Aadhar" maxlength="12" placeholder="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" pattern="\d*" required>
```

It worked to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```js
function numOnly(id) {
    // Get the element by id
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    // Use numbers only pattern, from 0 to 9 with \-
    var regex = /[^0-9\-]/gi;
    // Replace other characters that are not in regex pattern
    element.value = element.value.replace(regex, "");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number" oninput="numOnly(this.id);" name="Aadhar" maxlength="14" placeholder="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}" required/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response however , I need to do it in HTML only ,no JS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use type="tel" and maxlength

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Use **max** instead of maxlength

```
<input type="number" name="Aadhar" max="12" placeholder="xxxx-xxxx-xxxx" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}" required>
```

When the user will click on Submit Button It will show that the value should be less than 12.
This can be only used inside a form.

Comment: I think this confuses max value with maxlength.