# Limiting number of characters in text input

Tags: javascript, html

Here I made a text input which displays 1000 devided by the vlaue of text range:

```
<input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="50" max="200" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);"><br>
<input type="text" id="fps" placeholder="fps" ><br>

<script>
function updateTextInput(val) {document.getElementById('fps').value=1000/val;}
</script>
```

The number results appear way beyond the decimal point. How can I limit the number of characters (for example 4 digits: 12.34) that appears on text input? `maxlength` doesn't seem to work here.

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: You are not alone on this,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome

Comment: @Andreas this is inspiring, thanks. I should have known better

Answer (score 3):

The `.toFixed(x)` method works, x=2 would limit to 2 decimals.

```
f = 12.456218;
a = f.toFixed(2);
console.log(a); // 12.45
```

If you want not only to limit the amount of decimals after the point but also the total number of digits, you will have to typecast to string and then work on that

Comment: `you will have to typecast to string`,  `.toFixed()` already returns a string

Comment: I meant that on a non-toFixed() number