# Input type max length based on what function value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have an array of objects which look like

```js
 {
    value: "text",
    length: 50,
    image_url: textPassword,
    type: "text"
  },
  {
    value: "number_lock_3",
    length: 3,
    image_url: numberLock3,
    type: "number"
  },
```

In my html, I have an input

passwordType() is one of the objects above.

This simply works when the type is text.

```html
<input 

:type="passwordType().type"
:maxlength="passwordType().length"

 />
```

I am trying to make maxlength for the inputs, but whenever the type is number, maxlength wont work, are there any custom methods that I could use to make max length for the input based on the `passwordType().length` ?

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome

Comment: or Check this: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_number

Comment: @Patfreeze this allows unlimited numbers.

Comment: The regExp thing wont work aswell: `<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{3}">`

Comment: allows any input but will failed on validation. You can use **onKeyup** event but you will need to create a callback function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `pattern` only works for validation

You can also try `max` (example below), but it will let you type any value in and enforce the max only when the / buttons are used

But the most reliable solution is likely to use an `@input` event listener to trim the value.

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data: () => ({
    passwordType: {
      value: "number_lock_3",
      length: 3,
      type: "number"
    }
  }),
  methods: {
    getMax(length) {
      return parseInt(''.padStart(length, '9'))
    },
    onKeydown(target, length) {
      target.value = target.value.substr(0, length)
    }
  },
}).mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.0/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input :type="passwordType.type" :max="getMax(passwordType.length)" /> max ( {{getMax(passwordType.length)}}) <br />
  <input :type="passwordType.type" @input="(e)=>{onKeydown(e.target, passwordType.length)}" /> @input <br />

  <input v-model="passwordType.length" type="number" /> length
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed