# Limit the amount of digits allowed in a Number Input javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a number input: `<input type = 'number>`, and I needed to know how to limit the amount of integers that you could insert into the input

So I came up with what's in the snippet, but are there any other solutions that may be faster to implement, or just better in general.

This question has a similar answer, but I am trying to scour the internet to see if there is a better answer to it.

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-can-i-limit-possible-inputs-in-a-html5-number-element)

EDIT: I have found the answer that works to it, and I am looking for something of a one liner that would work. Something like the `max = '4'` or the input's version of it `maxlength = '4'`

```js
const Input  = document.getElementById('input')

function limitDigits(element, amount) {
  element.addEventListener('input', () => {
    if (element.value.length > amount) {
        element.value = Math.floor(element.value/10)
      } 
  }) 
}
 
limitDigits(Input, 4)
```

```css
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
#input {
  width:30px;
}
```

```html
<input id = 'input' type = 'number'>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I limit possible inputs in a HTML5 "number" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354975/how-can-i-limit-possible-inputs-in-a-html5-number-element)

Comment: @Kinglish The problem with that is you can still manually input numbers set over that max, its just when you use the slider.

Comment: there was also some `oninput` event javascript in that post that showed how to check and trim input that is too large.

Comment: Yes, and that was very similar to what I have, I was wondering if there was a better solution to the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing more efficient (especially if you are using this functionality more than once) would be to make it more reusable - that way you don't have to instantiate it each time through code.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('[maxlength]').forEach(input => {
    input.addEventListener('input', e => {
    let val = e.target.value, len = +e.target.getAttribute('maxlength');
      e.target.value = val.slice(0,len);
    })
  })
})
```

```css
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

#input {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<input maxlength='4' type='number'>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is very nice. I was thinking of closing this question since everyone was linking me to one that was very different.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [maxlength](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp) attribute to do this:

```html
<input id='input' type='text' maxlength='10'>
```

Unfortunately, this does not work on input of type number. A workaround can be found here: [maxlength ignored for input type="number" in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome)

Comment: That doesn't work for `type='number'` inputs

Comment: Comment on your edit, for some reason the `pattern` element does not work for me, and although I could include a similar answer with regex, I just want to limit the amount of numbers in specifically a `<input type = 'number'>`

Comment: In that case, I guess going with an oninput event would be best. Check out the second answer on the linked questions. Pretty similar to what you already had but a bit more concise.

Comment: Do you think that I should close my question then?

Answer (score 0):

A good place to learn about HTML is MDN, which has [a dedicated page for `<input type="number">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number).

The list of attributes includes:

> max
>
> The maximum value to accept for this input.

Note that a number field is designed to represent *an actual numeric value*, not a string which happens to be made up of digits. So rather than "less than 4 digits long", you need to say "a value less than or equal to nine thousand, nine hundred and ninety-nine":

```html
<input id='input' type='number' max='9999'>
```

Comment: Although this solution works, the biggest problem is that the `max` value only accepts it with the side arrows, but when you manually input it, it goes over the value

Comment: @ZainWilson-WCHStudent It will also fail [constraint validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Constraint_validation) when you try to submit the form.

Comment: The problem is is that it is not included in a form, I just need a number input

Comment: @ZainWilson-WCHStudent You could trigger the validation manually on some other event. Or you could stick with your custom solution, since you're not really using it in the way the spec intended anyway.

Comment: Do you believe that I should close my question then?

Answer (score 0):

> Solution given by HTML5, add attribute of min and max and uou good to go.

Comment: Sorry, but in chrome the min max value do not prevent you from being able to input a higher value that what you set.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this though the use of a module

```
HTMLElement.prototype.limitDigits = function (max) {
    this.addEventListener('input', () => {
        if (this.value.length > max) {
            this.value = Math.floor(this.value/10)
        }
    })
}
```

```js
HTMLElement.prototype.limitDigits = function (max) {
    this.addEventListener('input', () => {
        if (this.value.length > max) {
            this.value = Math.floor(this.value/10)
        }
    })
} //Element.limitDigits(maxLength)

const Input = document.getElementById('input');
const InputTwo = document.getElementById('input2');

Input.limitDigits(4);
InputTwo.limitDigits(1);
```

```css
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
}
input {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
Default: <input type = 'number'>
<br><br>
Limit is set to 4 Digits: <input id = 'input' type = 'number'>
<br> <br>
Litmit is set to 1 Digit:<input id = 'input2' type = 'number'>
```

Answer (score -2):

This should get you there

```js
    function limit(element){
        var max_num = 4;

        if(element.value.length > max_num) {
            element.value = element.value.substr(0, max_chars);
        }
    }
```

```html
<input type="number" onkeydown="limit(this);" onkeyup="limit(this);">
```

Comment: Yes, that is my exact snippet thank you though.