# Maxlength for input type number

Tags: html, forms

I have a number input field in HTML.

```
  <input type="number" value="0">
```

and I'd like for the user to not be able to type more than five characters into the textbox.

I've used the `maxlength` attribute before when the type is set to `text`, but that doesn't work with the `number` attribute. Is there a relatively simple solution (inline HTML is preferred) to overcome this and limit the number of characters?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a maximum of 5 digits in the number, you can use the largest 5 digit number and set that as the `max` attribute for the input:

```html
<input type="number" max="99999" />
```

The above will only maximize the number to `99999`, but will not disallow input of more than 5 characters. This can't be done with HTML alone.

It can, though, be done with JavaScript. For example:

```html
<input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
    type="number"
    maxlength="5"
 />
```

All the code above does is, `oninput`, it checks the number of characters in the `input`, and if that is exceeding the number of characters specified in `maxlength`, it deletes the character.

---

Source: [maxlength ignored for input type="number" in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome)

Comment: Just tried it, it doesn't actually limit the number of characters, rather, it comes back as an invalid element.

Comment: Oh ok, so you wanted a limit on the number of characters that can be typed into the `input` field?

Comment: Yes, that's the kind of thing that I'm looking for.

Comment: I've done some research and it doesn't look like this can be done with HTML alone. I can update the answer with a JavaScript solution, if wanted.

Comment: If possible, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Alrighty, done!

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I think firstly you have to remove value ="0" and use maxlength it will work.