# How to set retrieved value as max input value on Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, web

I'm trying to set a max attribute based on the retrieved value in my database but it doesn't seem to work for me.

These is the codes that I tried

```
//
<input type="number" name="entered_qty" placeholder="Enter Quantity" min="1" max="<?=$data->store_quantity?>" required>
//
<input type="number" name="entered_qty" placeholder="Enter Quantity" min="1" max="{{$data->store_quantity}}" required>
```

I also tried to retrieve it as `value="{{$data->store_quantity}}"` to see if I'm able to retrieve the value in my database and it does. Furthermore there data types in my database are `int`

but if I do it manually like this, it works just fine

```
<input type="number" name="entered_qty" placeholder="Enter Quantity" min="1" max="5" required>
```

this is also how I retrieve it in my database in my controller

```
public function products($encryption_id){
    $encrypt_id = Crypt::decrypt($encryption_id);
    $data=product::where('id',$encrypt_id)->first();

    return view("admin.products",compact("data"));
}
```

What should I do?

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome

Comment: are you referring to `maxlenght` ?, but what I'm trying is the max value

Comment: `it doesn't seem to work for me`. How it doesn't seem to work to you? Is there any exception thrown, what's shown for `max` attribute? What's the result you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{$data->store_quantity}}` may not be an integer or number or may be smaller than 0.

Try this:

```
@if(is_int($data->store_quantity) && $data->store_quantity  > 0)
    <input type="number" name="entered_qty" placeholder="Enter Quantity" min="1" max="{{$data->store_quantity}}" required>
@else
    // The data ur ($data->store_quantity) may not be an integer or it's smaller than 0...
    <p>"Error: Data received is not an integer or number or its smaller than 0"</p>
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks, it's already fixed, as what you mentioned is the problem, had to update the imported data in my database as it was the one affected.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the user using the dropdown as shown below.

```
  <select name="entered_qty">
    <option value="0">Select Quantity</option>
    @if(empty($data->store_quantity))
      @for ($i = 1; $i < $data->store_quantity; $i++)
        <option value="{{$i}}">{{$i}}</option>
      @endfor
    @endif
  </select>
```