# Number input limiting max length

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, input

I have a simple number input in react component. I need to make it not accept more than 4 characters. But it doesn't work with maxLength attribute. What else i can do to prevent it taking more than 4 characters.

```
<input type="number" onchange={handleChange} 



<input type="number"/>




/>
```

Comment: You can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510845/maxlength-ignored-for-input-type-number-in-chrome).

Answer (score 1):

The handleChange function checks if the input value is greater than or equal to -9999 or less than equal to 9999.

```
import "./styles.css";

import React, { useState } from "react";

export default App = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const nextValue = event.target.value;

    if (nextValue >= 0 && nextValue <= 9999) {
      setInputValue(nextValue);
    }
    if (nextValue < 0 && nextValue * -1 <= 9999) {
      setInputValue(nextValue);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="fourCharInput">Enter up to 4 digit number:</label>
      <input type="number" value={inputValue} onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you wanna play around with the code, here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/awesome-meninsky-wg9dcs?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A5%2C29).

Comment: but your input is type text, i can achieve it in type text , but not in type number. It doesn't work with that. If you have any ideas for that i would be grateful.

Comment: @KonulMemmedova Thanks for pointing this out! I have made the required changes here and on the sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

you can add readonly attribute to the input when your hook gets 4 characters

Answer (score 0):

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    let inputValue = event.target.value;

    
    if (!isNaN(inputValue) && inputValue.length > 4) {
      setError('Please enter only up to 4 digits.');
    
      inputValue = inputValue.slice(0, 4);
    } else {
      setError('');
    }

    setValue(inputValue);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="number"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      {error && <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error}</p>}//print the error
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Did you read *all* of the OP's post? They used `maxLength` attribute and it doesn't work.