# How to fix length of input text in specific size? in HTML 5

Tags: javascript, html

i want to use like this maxlength and minlength both. But it is not working. length of text should be in between 3 to 10 characters

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" autofocus required maxlength= "10" minlength= "3">
```

using these maxlength is functioning but minlength not..
but only minlength is working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555143/html-maxlength-attribute-not-working-on-chrome-and-safari

Comment: This might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281962/is-there-a-minlength-validation-attribute-in-html5

Comment: Here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841363/how-to-restrict-number-of-characters-that-can-be-entered-in-html5-number-input-f

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative way of doing it in HTML, here it is

```html
<form>
  <label for="name">Name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" required minlength="3" maxlength="10" size="10">

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also validate the character length with `pattern` attribute like this:

```html
<form>
  <label for="username">Userame:</label>
<input name="username" pattern=".{3,10}" required title="3 to 10 characters">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>

<h1>The input maxlength attribute</h1>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username" maxlength="10" minlength="5"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one, I have checked and this works.

```
<form>
   <label for="username">Userame:</label>
   <input type="text" name="txtName" minlength="3" maxlength="10" required>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```